# How to share classes between DAL and BLL using SQLite?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-runtime

For example, the Data Access Layer defines:

```
public class Customer
{

    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The attributes are used by `SQLite` for mapping the table. The problem is that I would need to use the `Customer` class in the BLL and also in the presentation layer. I want to isolate the DAL implementation in order to avoid to add references to `SQLite` to upper layers.
Obviously if I try to add the `Customer` class in a `Common.dll` assembly without `SQLite` references, the problem are the `SQLite` attributes.

I could create another `Customer` class, for example `CustomerBase` and to map the values from `Customer` to `CustomerBase`. It seems too tedious for me specially because I manage many data classes.

Which approach can be recommended for this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I would say data access layers should be separated from business layer dtos. So just have your sqllite entities in the data access layer and then another dto (data transfer objects ) in BLL and then use mapping between the two objects

Comment: Yes, it is what I explain in the last part of my question. I agree, dtos are shared by DAL and BLL but I feel that most of them are the same to sqlite entities. I manage more than 100 dtos, it means at least 100 sqlite entities more, and the the code to map each pair of objects, usually with properties 1=1. It seems too tedious to me. In my former projects using other platforms, I could "reuse" the dto in my DAL to create a new sql entiry deriving the dto class. Now, since I need to use the attributes, I cannot reuse them.